# .NET Core 6/EF Core 6.referencing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-6.0

We've created a Web API using .NET Core 6 and EF Core 6. In development environment all works good but when I do the publish application fails with an error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=2.0.20168.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5'

Deeper down the stack trace it references EF Core operations.

EF Core is dependent on `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version 2.1.4 and that version exists in publish. Any idea what when wrong here?

Thanks a lot, Miki

Comment: I saw this discussed somewhere recently.. Github maybe.. Be careful not to conflate product versions with File versions. That 2.1.4 and 2.0.20168.4 are not related

Comment: *that version exists in publish* - is it actually published to the server? Have you got any active binding redirects?

Comment: No, I don't have active binding redirects. Yes, published to the server but if I run it locally on IIS it is not working as well.

Comment: A was playing with it some more so if I publish with VS application works. Published version on CI server is not working on both test server or mine machine when I download the artifact. I'll check what are the differences between those two publish versions.

Comment: On VS published version that works there is a runtimes folder which does not exist on CI published version.

Comment: When you publish it takes the file from the RELEASE folder.  It is possible you were testing with the executables in the DEBUG folder. Make sure the debug and release folders are both compiled with latest source code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the effort.

I found what was the problem.

My dotnet publish command needed `--self-contained --runtime win-x64` so it includes runtime and the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine.

Cheers, Miki

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

> dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained --verbosity d

Answer (score 0):

I also face a same error. I resolved it by adding Nugget PackegeReference in my solution.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.1" />
```